# Storing liquor out of sunlight for a home bar in a Florida sunroom?

Tags: storage, cocktails, temperature, bartending

I've found posts on storage of liquor at home (e.g. [this](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/6601/how-should-one-store-liquors-in-a-home-bar)), but is there any advice out there for storing liquor out of sunlight for a home bar in a Florida sunroom? In the past, I've learned direct sunlight is a no-no, but I also do see beach bars and other places that do seem to successfully serve alcohol in a hot environment. So a couple of specific questions about this scenario...

1. Should I be looking for some kind of fridge that keeps alcohol at room temperature? I don't want it cold but I'm guessing 90 deg F is too warm for storage of open bottles.
2. Do beach bars and the like just bring alcohol in and out every day? Should I be looking for a "bar cart" style setup where I can bring things inside after entertaining? Tell me I don't need to find a mini split and just cool my whole sunroom all the time?

I have a whole house, but my sunroom is the best for entertaining. How does one do a home bar in this environment without hauling stuff back and forth every time? I'd actually love to use that square footage for storage...

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a photo of your sunroom?

Comment: Not sure I want to put photos of it on the internet, but it's essentially windows across two walls, and then french doors and window-into-house on the other two walls.

Answer (score 1):

**Sunroom in Florida and building a home bar**

I understand your fear about posting photos about your sunroom on the net!

In that case I will try to make a generic recommendation.

Make a lockable cabinet, under a counter or closet that can be used to store your alcohol. I would recommend that it be made of hardwood and well insulated. After taking some council from professionals, I would place a an **air conditioner** or **air cooler** in it that would not be seen externally.

Try to keep direct sunlight of your area of placement for your alcohol!

Air coolers come in various sizes and can be mounted on walls or ceilings. I have seen the ceiling air coolers used to preserve fruit and vegetables.

Searching the net you may find what you can adopt to your situation. Search and you will find! The following is simply an example of my thinking:

> [**AIR COOLERS**](https://www.guntner.com/products/air-coolers)
>
> With nearly a century of technological and engineering excellence, our air coolers are second to none. High quality, robust and reliable products – give your business the very best.
>
> A wide range of Güntner air cooler products come with an HACCP certification too, to meet your country’s hygiene requirements.
>
> **Slim Compact**
>
> High efficiency in a slimline design, this space-saver is made with small and low cold stores in mind. The flat design occupies very little space allowing optimal use of your cold room.
>
> [image: SLIM COMPACT]

If need be, you can always use a refrigerator.